# phpmailer does not work for Persian letters

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a problem that the subject is printed for Persian letters like this:
ØªØ³Øª
I changed Cherst to utf-8 but the problem was not resolved
body has no problem with Persian letters, the only problem is the subject

Comment: You might want to manually base64-encode your subject once you're **sure** it's UTF-8 (or any other charset):
`$phpmailer->Subject = '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=';`

Comment: Very thankful
thank you so much
The problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

$phpmailer->Subject = '=?UTF-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=';

Answer (score 0):

Don't encode your subject yourself; it will interfere with PHPMailer's processing. To get PHPMailer to handle it for you, just do this:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```

After that make sure that all your other text processing is in UTF-8 (e.g. your database), and it will all work.